# Traveling with Cooked Chicken

Tags: chicken

My family suggested the process of grilling chicken on a thursday, freezing, traveling 8 hours by car (with meat on ice) on Friday, then reheating to serve on Saturday. Is this safe to consume?

Comment: Related (although it's traveling w/ raw chicken) : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16428/67

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The chicken cannot be at above 40 degrees for more than 2 hours. If it is frozen, and kept on ice it might be fine. I would store it with a thermometer and periodically check that it is still an appropriate temperature. If it stays frozen or refrigerator temperature for at least 6 of those hours, then you're fine.